# Why does the removal of an entity from a collection in the following example not get propagated?

Tags: java, orm, jpa-2.0

This problem is probably due to my ignorance when it comes to what JPA can and cannot do, so hopefully someone will be able to enlighten me. In short, the removal of an entity from a collection does not get propagated to the in-memory instance of its grandparent. Following is an example scenario.

We have three entities (A, B, C).

```
@Entity
public class C {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
  private B b;
  ...
}
```

And,

```
@Entity
public class B {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
  private Set<C> cs;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
  private A a;
  ...
}
```

And,

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade ={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
  private Set<B> bs;
  ...
}
```

Next, we have a stateless session bean for modifying instances of B.

```
@Stateless
public class BServiceBean implements BService {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = Constants.PU)
  EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public B updateB(B b) {
    return em.merge(b);
  }

  @Override
  public B removeC(int bId, int cId) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    B b = em.find(B.class, bId);

    if (null == b) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No b with id: " + bId + " exists.");
    }
    C c = em.find(C.class, cId);

    if (null == c) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No c with id: " + cId + " exists.");
    }
    b.getCs().remove(c);
    em.remove(c);
    return em.merge(b);
  }
}
```

We modify a bunch of these entities in a servlet via a container-injected BService instance.

```
// created and persisted an A with three Bs, one of which has three Cs. 
A a = ...;
b2.setName(changedName);
b2 = bService.updateB(b2); // this change is reflected in a
...
b2 = bService.removeC(b2.getId(), c1.getId()); // this change is not reflected in a

// but it is in the db
a = aService.findAById(a.getId); // this instance of a has a b2 without a c1
```

Why does the removal of an entity from the collection in B not cascade upon merge to A, even though the change of a basic field in B does cascade to A on merge of B? And is there anything I can do to cause JPA to cascade the entity removal upwards to A?

Answer (score 0):

You have cascade only persist and merge You should also need cascade the removal. Simply add following type to cascade add, update and remove.

```
cascade =CascadeType.ALL
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I change the cascade on all entities to CascadeType.ALL?